# How to Unit Test with Qunit a Knockout View Model that uses throttle on observables

Tags: unit-testing, knockout.js, qunit

Supposed this is my view model

```
function VM()
{
    var self = this;

    this.Status = ko.observable(false);

    this.A = ko.observable();

    this.B = ko.computed(
        function()
        {
            return self.A();
        }
    ).extend( throttle: 200 );

    this.B.subscribe(
        function()
        {
            self.Status(true);

            setTimeout( //ajax simulation
                function(){
                    self.Status(false);
                }

            ,200)
        }
    );

}
```

I want a test that verifies status toggles between true and false as A is set but i can't get past the dual async nature of the VM.  Is there a way to test this with multiple stop()/start() calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only what to test that the `Status` toggles between `true` and `false` I would just subscribe on the `Status` change and check in the change callback that the first time I get the value `true` and the second time the value `false`.

Writing your test this way you would need to have one start/stop pair, something like this:

```
asyncTest("computed with ajax", function () {
    expect(2); // expecting two asserts, so the Status only changes twice
    var sut = new VM();
    // multiple calls to A to test the throttle behavior
    sut.A('something');
    sut.A('something2');
    sut.A('something3');
    stop();
    var callCount = 0;
    var expectedValues = [true, false];
    sut.Status.subscribe(function (value) {
        start();
        equal(sut.Status(), expectedValues[callCount]);
        callCount++;
    });
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MzXLM/)

Comment: that's an interesting approach, it's like Reactive testing, where you verify the event sequence emitting from the observable matches the expectations...i'll have to think about that and try to apply it to my much more complex real VM.

Comment: @ChrisDaMour have you managed to apply this testing idea on your real VM?