# Have useful "Red" and "Green" tests for a View Model with throttled observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, qunit

With help of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17303722/419956) and the [relevant QUnit documentation](http://api.qunitjs.com/category/async-control/) I can create unit tests that deal with the async nature of [throttled KnockoutJS observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html).

However, I haven't yet found an elegant way to have both Red and Green tests behave nicely in *both* test runners I use:

- the QUnit browser based test runner
- the Visual Studio test runner (combined with [Chutzpah](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/) to run JavaScript tests)

Suppose the following View Model:

```
var Person = function(firstName, surname) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    self.surname = ko.observable(surname);

    self.fullName = ko.computed({
        write: function(val) {
            var parts = val.split(" ");
            self.firstName(parts[0]);
            self.surname(parts[1]);
        },
        read: function() { return self.firstName() + " " + self.surname(); }
    }).extend({throttle: 20});
};
```

And suppose these two basic tests:

```
test("Can read full name", function(){
    var john = new Person("John", "Doe");
    strictEqual(john.fullName(), "John Doe");
});


test("Can write full name", function(){
    var person = new Person();
    person.fullName("John Doe");
    strictEqual(person.firstName(), "John");
    strictEqual(person.surname(), "Doe");
});
```

The latter [will fail](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/1/). This makes sense, because the asserts run instantly, whereas the actual update for the `fullName` call runs later: it is delayed by 20 ms by the `throttle`. Without throttle [things succeed](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/3/).

No problem, from linked question I learned that I can use an [async test](http://api.qunitjs.com/asyncTest/) and use a manual subscription to make things green again:

```
asyncTest("Can write full name", function(){
    var person = new Person();

    expect(2);

    person.surname.subscribe(function(val) {
        start();
        strictEqual(person.firstName(), "John");
        strictEqual(person.surname(), "Doe");
    });    

    person.fullName("John Doe");
});
```

Now, suppose I break my View Model like this:

```
// self.surname(parts[1]); // "bug" introduced to demonstrate the problem
```

Then the [test runner will hang](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/6/). I can "fix" this issue by resuming my test after -say- 2 seconds no matter what by ending my test with this:

```
// After 2 secs we assume the test failed
setTimeout(function() {
    start();
}, 2000);
```

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/7/) in the browser based test runner for the bugged code, but [has an error](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/8/) on the correct code, from the console:

> pushFailure() assertion outside test context, was ... at QUnit.start

Makes sense, because now `start()` is called twice. My first intuition was to do a check in the `setTimeout` callback to see the "trancount" (i.e. ask QUnit if I need to start or not), but QUnit has no support for this (probably for a reason :D).

Anyways, to sum up all possible situations:

- Green because everything is okay.
- Red because the subscription never fired.
- Red because the assertion failed.

How to structure the test so that all situations are accounted for and both test runners will react nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found at least one solution to this problem while writing the question. Posting the question along with my answer (a) just in case it may help others and/or (b) other folks may have better solutions for this.

Bottom line is to clear the `setTimeout` return value as soon as the subscription fires:

```
asyncTest("Can write full name", function(){
    var person = new Person();

    // After 2 secs we assume the test failed
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        start();
    }, 2000);

    expect(2);

    person.surname.subscribe(function(val) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        start();
        strictEqual(person.firstName(), "John");
        strictEqual(person.surname(), "Doe");
    });

    person.fullName("John Doe");
});
```

This works for all scenarios:

- Green [if all is well](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/9/).
- Red [if the subscription never fires](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/10/).
- Red [if the code has a bug](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/11/).

Both red cases have a nice assertion failure.

Only downside to this solution is that it's a bit verbose, you need 4 extra lines of testing-plumbing. (Perhaps someone else has an answer utilizing a feature of QUnit for this purpose?)

Also, one other downside: if you increase the throttle so it is above the timeout the test first goes red but QUnit [will crash](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/13/) a bit later too because `start()` is called once more.

Comment: You could use some form of a promise to deal with the last issue, e.g. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmuV/14/)