# Correct separation of qunit test files from knockout viewmodels

Tags: knockout.js, resharper, qunit

I have an issue getting qunit and resharper to recognise certain viewmodels within visual studio. I am sure it is down to my separation of files but I cannot work out exactly what it is. The working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9nfzS/1/

The problem occurs when I separate the tests from the viewmodel. The files belong in different projects (but the problem also occurs when they are in the same project, just different files). The file contents are as follows:

**ListTests.js**

```
/// <reference path="List.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js" />
$(function() {

    module("test desk retrieval");

    test("initial item length", function () {
        QUnit.equal(deskns.viewmodel.desks().length, 0, "desks length");
    });

    test("initial description is empty", function () {
        QUnit.equal(deskns.viewmodel.newDescription(), '', "new description");
    });

    test("does this work at all", function () {
        QUnit.equal(1, 1);
    });
});
```

**List.js**

```
var deskns = deskns || {};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(deskns.viewmodel);
});

deskns.DeskItem = function (params) {
    params = params || {};
    this.id = ko.observable(params.ID || '');
    this.name = ko.observable(params.name || "<New>");
    this.description = ko.observable(params.description || "<New>");
    this.memberCount = ko.observable(params.memberCount || 0);
    this.isActive = ko.observable(params.isActive || true);
}

deskns.viewmodel = (function () {

    var
        desks = ko.observableArray(),
        addDesk = function () {
            desks.push(new deskns.DeskItem({ name: newName(), description: newDescription() }));
            clearInputs();
        },
        clearInputs = function () {
            newName('');
            newDescription('');
        },
        newName = ko.observable(""),
        newDescription = ko.observable("");

    return {
        desks: desks,
        add: addDesk,
        newName: newName,
        newDescription: newDescription
    }
})();
```

The reference paths are correct but running these tests in the resharper runner gives the errors:

```
Died on test #1: Cannot call method 'newDescription' of undefined - {}
Died on test #1: Cannot call method 'desks' of undefined - {}
```

so the viewmodel is undefined. The same code in the fiddle works perfectly and the underlying code also works as expected, I just can't get any tests to run. Does anyone have any idea what this is - it has been driving me absolutely nuts all day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Unit Test with Qunit a Knockout View Model that uses throttle on observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303722/how-to-unit-test-with-qunit-a-knockout-view-model-that-uses-throttle-on-observab)