# qunit testing ajax through knockout viewmodel

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js, qunit

I have an issue using qunit to test a knockout viewmodel function which calls an async (ajax) routine itself. I understand the use of asyncTest but it just doesn't seem to fit. Normally this would lead me to a refactor of the model but I like the way it works at the moment (rightly or wrongly!). The scenario is outlined below.

The issue is that I don't want/need to test the ajax function itself. 'loadDesks' is the public function of the viewmodel and, as such, is the unit I really want to put under test. However, this has no callback so I cannot instruct qunit to call start() when it completes as there is no callback to the test routine.

So, in the code below, the test fails as the async ajax calls returns to qunit before the async call has completed and populated the observable array - as expected. However the commented hack in the test to wait an arbitrary amount of time is extremely brittle. The pattern is obviously wrong somewhere but I am struggling to see how, can anyone help?

Obviously making this call synchronous fixes it but I have to do that in the real call to make it take effect on the mock and that isn't really acceptable.

**Viewmodel**

```
deskns.viewmodel = (function () {
    var
        desks = ko.observableArray(),
        loadDesks = function () {
            deskns.Ajax.loadDesks(reloadDeskArray, ajaxErrorHandler);
        },
        reloadDeskArray = function (data) {
            desks.removeAll();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                addRow(data[i]);
            }
        },
        addRow = function (data) {
            desks.push(new deskns.Desk({
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
                description: data.description,
                isActive: data.isActive,
                activeUserCount: data.userCount
            }));
        }
    };
    return {
        desks: desks,
        loadDesks : loadDesks
    }; 
})();
```

**Ajax js file**

```
deskns.Ajax = (function() {
    var
        callback = function (func, data) {
            if (typeof (func) == 'function') {
                func(data);
            }
        },
        loadDesks = function (successFunc, errorFunc) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Desk/List',
                success: function (data) { callback(successFunc, data); },
                error: function (data) { callback(errorFunc, data); }
            });
        };
    return {
        loadDesks: loadDesks
    }
})();
```

**Test and mock**

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/Desk/List',
    contentType: "text/json",
    responseText: JSON.stringify([{ id: '1', name: 'testname', description: 'testdescr', isActive: true, activeUserCount: 1 }])
});

test("listing desks displays items", function () {
    vm.loadDesks();
    deepEqual(vm.desks().length, 1, 'desk length is one when one user is loaded');

    /* Here comes the hack
    setTimeout(function() {
        start();
        deepEqual(vm.desks().length, 1, 'desk length is one when one user is loaded');
    }, 500);
        */
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Unit Test with Qunit a Knockout View Model that uses throttle on observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303722/how-to-unit-test-with-qunit-a-knockout-view-model-that-uses-throttle-on-observab)